# VBA SMALL( malfunctions

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code which pastes the SMALL function on a dynamic length and is therefore looped. When I remove the "=" in the "=SMALL..." and add those by hand in the cell it works as intended, however the Macro crashes with a 1004 error.

```
For i = 1 To Iterations
Range("output!C1").Offset(i, 0) = "=SMALL(output!$B$2:output!$B$" & [SimNumber] & ";OFFSET(output!A1;" & [i] & ";0))"
Next i
```

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. I have a different Active Worksheet but I do not think that's the problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to use Formula: `Range("output!C1").Offset(i, 0).Formula = "=SMALL(output!$B$2:output!$B$" & [SimNumber] & ";OFFSET(output!A1;" & [i] & ";0))"`

Comment: Sadly gives the same error..

Comment: When I change `;` to `,` for my regional setting it works fine.  Are you sure your regional settings are set for `;`?  I get your 1004 error when using `;`

Comment: That solved it. When I manually enter formulas in cells I have to use the **;** but apparantly I have to use **,** in VBA... Thanks!